Complex gradient image in tailwind
I wanted to know if it was possible to combine bg-gradient-* to make a complex one such as :

as you can see the image is composed of two linear gradients bg-gradient-to-r on top and bottom and they are bleeding into one an other with a bg-gradient-to-t like behaviour.
I would like to be able to reproduce my image with tailwind

You will need to have two or more different divs with absolute positioning and apply gradient, but I'm not sure if it is best practice.
